# how to create new form in admin side in prestashop

Tags: forms, prestashop

how to create new form for admin side in prestashop.

I have try some other controllers to create new forms, but it make very confuse.

I have created separate table and insert data from the form and the list and editing the content.

```
any separate module for adding ,editing and listing .
```

Comment: Can you be more specific where you want the form, i think you should make a simple module.

Comment: Are you using prestashop v1.5+?
Are you coding a module?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a module with a controller class that extends ModuleAdminController, and inside the controller class, can use the renderForm() method.